# Sample project using 'xcode-plugin' from org.openbakery.xcode-plugin

Tags: xcode, maven, kotlin-multiplatform

Has anyone worked with KMP projects and publishing Xcode frameworks or apps to Maven?  I believe it's possible with this a plugin from 'org.openbakery.xcode-plugin', but I have been unable to do this?  Is there a 'HelloWorld' project or such that someone could share?  We're using a 'monorepo' for our apps and components (frameworks).  While we can publish Android to maven, we that Cocoapods greatly increases our build times as it's building multiple levels of 'pods'.  So, we think we can work around the Cocoapod issues using maven.

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial for an empty iOS project using OpenBakery's Xcode plugin (https://openbakery.org/gxp/getting-started.html).

Create Xcode project and add 'build.gradle' file with the following:

```
    plugins {
//    id "org.openbakery.xcode-plugin" version "0.20.0"  <-- latest version isn't available currently
    id "org.openbakery.xcode-plugin" version "0.19.1"
}

xcodebuild {
    target = 'Example'
}
```

Now, I can use gradle commands like:

```
gradle xcodebuild
gradle assemble
gradle tasks
```